# Mail pdf Attachment using Rotativa

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rotativa

Sending the email and the attachment actaly works. my issue is i get this error when trying to send the "generated pdf"

An exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in Rotativa.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Error: Failed loading page http://localhost:49224/Offer/OfferPdf/4 (sometimes it will work just to ignore this error with --load-error-handling ignore)

The mail test in the controller:

```
 public ActionResult MailTest()
    {



        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
        msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(CoEmail));
        msg.From = new MailAddress(MailFrom, UserName);
        msg.Subject = "Offer";
        msg.Body = "This is a Test";
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(OffersPdfMail (4, "Offer"));
        Attachment att1 = new Attachment(stream, "Offer.pdf", "application/pdf");
        msg.Attachments.Add(att1);
        msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
        msg.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        msg.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Default;

        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(User, Pass);
        client.Port = 587; // 
        client.Host = "smtp.office365.com";
        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        try
        {
            client.Send(msg);
            return RedirectToAction("index");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

    }
```

The Byte[]:

```
 public Byte[] OfferPdfMail(int? id, string filename)
    {
  var mailpdft = new ActionAsPdf("OfferPdf/4")
        {
            FileName = "Offer",
            PageSize = Rotativa.Options.Size.A4,






            PageWidth = 210,

            PageHeight = 297

        };
        Byte[] PdfData = mailpdft.BuildPdf(ControllerContext);
        return PdfData;
```

and last the ViewasPdf:

```
      public ActionResult OfferPdf (int? id, string filename)
    {
        string footer = "test" ;
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }




        var pdf = new ViewAsPdf("TilbudsPdf") {
            FileName = filename,
            PageSize = Rotativa.Options.Size.A4,

            PageOrientation = Rotativa.Options.Orientation.Portrait,

            PageMargins = new Rotativa.Options.Margins(12, 12, 12, 12),// it’s in millimeters

            PageWidth = 210,

            PageHeight = 297,
            CustomSwitches = footer };

        return pdf;
    }
```

Editted the names to english. may have missed some.
Thanks for your patience, and sorry for the bad english.
Best regards Eric

Answer (score 0):

I found an solution, it was because i was stupid trying to making an pdf of a pdf. so i made a new ActionResult method like this:

```
public ActionResult tilbudspdfMailView(int? id, string filename)
    {
        Offer Offer= db.Offer.Find(id);

        return View("OfferPdf", Offer);
}
```